# Concatenate to existing value in xlst

Tags: xslt-1.0

With XSLT 1.0 I simply want to add a negative sign before the value in the Identifier element. The stylesheet I have shown below returns the same (i.e. the first instance) Identifier value for each instance of RToP. There can be more than one RToP. PLease advise how to modify the match so I return the desired output below. Thanks. I'm omitting the namespace in the xml below.

```
<TRAN><DE><REF>
<RToP><Identifier>100</Identifier>
</RToP>
<RToP><Identifier>150</Identifier>
</RToP>
</TRAN></DE></REF>
```

Existing output

```
<TRAN><DE><REF>
<RToP><Identifier>-100</Identifier>
</RToP>
<RToP><Identifier>-100</Identifier>
</RToP>
</TRAN></DE></REF>
```

Desired output

```
<TRAN><DE><REF>
<RToP><Identifier>-100</Identifier>
</RToP>
<RToP><Identifier>-150</Identifier>
</RToP>
</TRAN></DE></REF>
```

Existing stylesheet

```
  <xsl:template match="//my:TRAN/my:DE/my:REF/my:RToP/my:Identifier[position()]">
    <my:Identifier>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('-', //my:TRAN/my:DE/my:REF/my:RToP/my:Identifier[position()])"/>
    </my:Identifier>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: If your template matches `Identifier` then `<xsl:value-of select="concat('-', .)"/>` should suffice. Read up on relative vs. absolute paths. -- P.S. The predicate of `[position()]` makes no sense.

Comment: BTW, if you values are numbers, then `<xsl:value-of select="- ." />` would be both simpler and more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of transformation you need to be use relative path instead of absolute path.

first you have to create at identical transformation to retain its structure.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

than you have to define Identifier as template that run only on Identifier and there is no need to use predicates for that.

```
<xsl:template match="Identifier">
    <Identifier>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('-', .)"/>
    </Identifier>
</xsl:template>
```